# How to repeat a command immediately after calling it?

Tags: functions, interactive, commands

I've just called an interactive function (i.e., a command).  I want to call it again, with the same arguments.  I know that I can call a keyboard macro again by using `e` right after running it the first time.  Is there something similar regarding interactive functions?

Comment: This must be a duplicate. This has been asked and answered before, I'm pretty sure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also `repeat-complex-command` (normally bound to <kbd>C-x ESC ESC</kbd> as well as several others (that's the one I use, so I remember that)).  This will go back further in the history to the last command that required interaction (i.e. prompted for input).

Comment: That's a great addition! This command is exactly what I was lacking in the previous answer. Wish I could accept both.

Comment: @MatthewRock : if this one is closer to the solution you had in mind, feel free to unaccept the answer I posted and accept this one instead.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for [`repeat`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Repeating.html), bound by default to `C-x z`.  The
first part of the docstring:

> `(repeat REPEAT-ARG)`
>
> Repeat most recently executed command.
>   If `REPEAT-ARG` is non-`nil` (interactively, with a prefix argument),
>   supply a prefix argument to that command.  Otherwise, give the
>   command the same prefix argument it was given before, if any.

If you use `evil`, you also have access to the beloved dot command
from Vim.

Comment: Nice! Too bad that it repeats **any** command - just repeated `next-line`...

Comment: Will the site keep both answers?  Someone doing a search and finding this question might actually be looking for either.  They are both useful in their own way.

Comment: @MAP: yes, all answers will remain on the site, so it won't be a problem to move the acceptance to the other answer.